# Need to fill in form data from json data . Not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, forms

Things are not important since I'm also trying this with jsfiddle, thus ruling out that isn't React.JS causing the form to not fill.
I have data from a file.  It should be in json format and goal is to hydrate (fill) form fields
Here is a fiddle of it:  https://jsfiddle.net/vp5kLxgs/

While it would be nice to use some map function or perhaps the ID of the form, I will settle for about anything that will just loop over the form.  I can change the form if needed  I plan on having ID and Name

form:

```
<form id="importantForm" role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="family1 Name">
            Family1 Name
          </label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="family1Name" id="family1Name" />
    .... // etc....
 </form>
```

javascript:

```
//document.getElementById("family1Name").value = "jack"

var json = {family1Name: "jack", family1Relationship: "", family1Phone: ""};

var form_data = new FormData();

for ( var key in json ) {
   form_data.append(key, json[key]);
   console.log('key', key)
   console.log('impor..[key]', json[key])
}
```

Manually setting family1Name with document.getElementById  that works...
but the looping over the data does not fill the form fields.

With console.log i can see the key and value , but I don't know how formdata is suppose to know to use my form of id="importantForm"   , does it need to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormData()` is not intended as a way to bind the data between a data structure and a form. That's what the UI frameworks/libraries (React, Vue, Angular, etc) were created for. `FormData` is intended to offer a way to build data structures that can be [easily submitted to the backend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

> It is primarily intended for use in sending form data, but can be used
>   independently from forms in order to transmit keyed data. The
>   transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method
>   would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set to
>   multipart/form-data

However, setting your form field values manually is pretty straight forward:

```
var json = {family1Name: "jack", family1Relationship: "brother", family1Phone: "00045555000"};

var form = $("#importantForm");

for (var key in json) {
    var selector = `input[name="${ key }"], textarea[name="${ key }"]`
    var input = $(form).find(selector)  
    input.val(json[key]);
  }
```

Comment: Oh i see,  got it

Comment: hmm,  `'$' is not defined` in my react page   $ is not just for jquery i know, but how do i use it ?

Comment: We can also pull it from the json file and load it to the state and render?

Comment: @AaminKhan  -  currently I pull the data from local storage as i store as json string , but the current solution i'm having an issue with as i guess that $ is jquery?

Comment: @JeremyMiller: Using jQuery in react is not a good practice, I have created a code sandbox fro you please check if it meets your need https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-tdd-uqqll

Comment: @JeremyMiller, yes the `$` in `$("#importantForm")` is the one from jQuery, 'cause I assumed you already have that included in your files

Comment: I didn't have it on that component file,  but since i did have it on 1 file , i copied the import and it works.    Any chance you could show an update with the pure javascript (no jquery )  in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sample JSON

```
const data = {
    family1Name: "Jack",
    family1Relationship: "None",
    family1Phone: "999"
  };
```

And put this following jsx inside your `<form></form>` tag, quite simple

```
{Object.keys(data).map(k => (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor={k}>{k}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          name={k}
          id={k}
          value={data[k]}
        />
      </div>
    ))}
```

This is the output

[image]